# Electric Wall oven with power/ Circuit Breaker?

Tags: electrical, walls, circuit-breaker, oven

I am attempting to replace my wall oven which was installed sometime in the 80's. I (think) I tripped all my circuit breakers and the wall oven still had power. Do I need to  turn off the main power to the house or what could it be?

Any advice or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you've already tried all of the circuit breakers, I think your next step is the main. Do you share walls with any neighbors? Do you have any sub panels?

Comment: Can you post a photo of your breaker panel please?

Answer (score 2):

Some homes have breakers in more than 1 location. Let me explain I have installed panels that the true main is at the meter and the panel that has all the lighting and outlets is a sub panel, check the box at your meter it may have several large breakers like 1 for the panel, 1 for the range and possibly 1 for out buildings and or RV pads in some cases this is a cheaper way to power the other devices because smaller feeder wires can be run to the main panel and possibly shorter feeders to the devices that are powered from the box at the meter.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, always throw the main. Always, always, always.

Once the wall oven is uninstalled, you'll have a junction box there so you can work with your circuit. You, or a competant electrician, needs to investigate and make sure that oven wasn't wired into the main lugs of the panel, or that the breaker didn't fail and, somehow, weld itself into the 'on' position.

Comment: There should be a breaker, if not the wiring was a major code violation, normally ovens are double pole, check for a sub panel. Knowing the locations of your breakers is important is it possible you are throwing breakers in a sub not connected to the oven.

Comment: True - as Ed said, be triple-sure you are dealing in the main panel, and not some random sub panel.

Comment: I don't agree, you want to confirm  that there is indeed an individual breaker for the oven and they didn't jury-rig it off the main bus...

Comment: Throwing the main will confirm that.

Comment: @NPM -- keep in mind "split bus" panels are a thing

Comment: OP said all the breakers are off, except the main. Throw the main, if power is still on, you're in the main lugs.

Comment: Almost certainly the wall oven is powered by 240 V from a 2-pole breaker. Do you see any 2-pole breakers in the area where you think you turned off all the breakers in the house? Do you have an electric clothes dryer? a central A/C unit? If so have you found the breakers for those? Look outside and see if there is a homeowner accessible door under the meter containing 2-pole breakers.